# Edit Mini Page Layout In Lightning

Tags: lightning, page-layout

How do you edit the fields displayed on the mini page layout within Lightning?  I've set it in Classic and it displays correctly, but in Lightning, when I hover, the popup only shows the record name.

Answer (score 4):

In lightning the mini page layout looks like it is controlled by the compact layout on hover and not the actual mini page layout .

Every object will have a compact layout ,clone and make a new compact layout and add necessary fields and you will see the lightning experience hovers reflect the compact layouts

[image]

The hover details

[image]

Comment: You are correct, they come from Compact Layout, same as Lightning Highlights panel at top of page layout. However, I am not sure if and how can you add related lists to hovers (as on your second screen). Any clues?

Comment: @Wookie88, was searching the same, and end up with the conclusion that Related lists are not editable as of now.. you will see the only case and opportunity related list..and if the object does not have any relation to the case and opportunity or it does not have these records then "No related information" is shown.